# I am not getting FLAVOR string in BuildConfig , it is Missing in BuildConfig in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, buildconfig

```
 How to generate the missing one ? public static final String FLAVOR = "";`
```

Missing FLAVOR  in BuildConfig in Android Studio.It should be like this

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.arkam.konk.look";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0";
}
```

But in my case getting like without this one    `public static final String FLAVOR = "";`

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.arkam.konk.look";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0";}
```

How to generate the missing one ???

Answer (score 1):

use : Build -> Clean Project and then File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. and then build your App on smartphone or emulator.

EDIT :
if it does't work, create a new project and copy your classes and codes in that!

Comment: even after creating a new project, the problem remains the same

Comment: what is your  gradle version?? try with update gradle and even android studio and SDK

Comment: we are having the exact same issue. Not sure if because the FLAVOR is an empty string. Where you able to resolve it and how? appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in the build.gradle of the module you want to show the FLAVOR string:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorDimensions "name"
        myFlavorName {
            dimension "name"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'flavorVariable1', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'flavorVariable2', '"hello world"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'flavorVariable3', '"foo"'
        }
    }
}
```